# $zopim is not defined

Tags: javascript, zendesk, zopim

Reading [the documentation](https://api.zopim.com/files/meshim/widget/controllers/LiveChatAPI-js.html) of Zopim (a.k.a Zendesk Chat):

> API calls must be inserted after the Live Chat Script and wrapped within $zopim(function() { ...  })

So I have a the Zopim script in `head` part of HTML:

```
<script>/*<![CDATA[*/window.zEmbed||function(e,t){ ... }("https://...);
/*]]>*/</script>
```

Then I added this at the end of HTML document:

```
$zopim(function() {
  $zopim.livechat.setName('Logged in name');
  $zopim.livechat.setEmail('user@somewhere.com');
});
```

And console says:

> $zopim is not defined

I think I have followed [the instructions](https://api.zopim.com/files/meshim/widget/controllers/LiveChatAPI-js.html) correctly. What did I miss?

Comment: Did you solve this?  I have the same issue exactly

Comment: No. I wrote an ugly hack with a timeout, I will post it as an answer

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've found a better solution (after submitting a request to support)

```
    zE(function() {
        $zopim(function() {
            $zopim.livechat.setName("{{\Auth::user()->name}}");
            $zopim.livechat.setEmail("{{\Auth::user()->email}}");
        });
    });
```

I was using a Zendesk Chat Code within Zendesk Support that is why I need to add Ze function to make it working using api.

**Edit**: check the [interesting comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43386548/zopim-is-not-defined/43910439#comment77925933_43910439) from [Jay Hewitt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1683027/jay-hewitt) and also his [answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44776355/1261552).

Comment: This depends on how you're embedding the javascript. If you're using the $zopim javascript this won't work, but if you're using the Zendesk Widget (zEmbed) then you still have an issue of zE (or zEmbed) not being loaded before this is run, so even in this instance, you need a wait loop.

Comment: thanks @Freefri, this resolved error but in my case widget not showing on Chrome, on Firefox it shows after first load. I am using with Angular 8

Answer (score 14):

This will loop, waiting for $zopim and $zopim.livechat to be loaded.
Once they're loaded it will stop looping.

```
var waitForZopim = setInterval(function () {
    if (window.$zopim === undefined || window.$zopim.livechat === undefined) {
        return;
    }
    $zopim(function() {
        $zopim.livechat.setName("{{\Auth::user()->name}}");
        $zopim.livechat.setEmail("{{\Auth::user()->email}}");
    });
    clearInterval(waitForZopim);
}, 100);
```